# The state transition matrix formula

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

Let $\epsilon$ be real parameter and $\Phi(t,t_0)$ be state transition matrix.
How we can prove following equation:
$$
\Phi(t+\epsilon,t_0)=\Phi(t,t_0)+\epsilon\frac{d}{dt}\Phi(t,t_0)+O(\epsilon^2)\\
\quad\quad\quad\quad\;\;\;=\Phi(t,t_0)+\epsilon A(t)\Phi(t,t_0)+O(\epsilon^2).
$$

Answer (score 0):

This follows directly, by taylor expansion (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series) of $\Phi(t,t_0)$ for $t$ and using the property $\frac{\delta}{\delta t} \Phi(t,t_0) = A(t)$:
\begin{align}
\Phi(t+\epsilon,t_0) &= \Phi(t,t_0) + \frac{1}{1!}\Phi'(t,t_0)\epsilon +  \frac{1}{2!}\Phi''(t,t_0)\epsilon^{2} + \frac{1}{3!}\Phi^{(3)}(t,t_0)\epsilon^{3} +\,\, ... \\
&=\Phi(t,t_0) + \frac{1}{1!}\Phi'(t,t_0)\epsilon +O(\epsilon^2)\\
&=\Phi(t,t_0)+\epsilon A(t)\Phi(t,t_0)+O(\epsilon^2)
\end{align}